# find not recursive when given a pattern on the command line

Tags: bash, find, quoting, wildcards, recursive

Imagine a source tree. There are xml files everywhere.

But since there is a XYZ.xml at the root of this tree it won't find my xml files.

```
find -iname *.xml
```

returns

```
./XYZ.xml
```

instead of

```
./XYZ.xml
./a/b/c/bob.xml
./b/d/top.xml
```

Comment: From `man find`: Please note that you should quote patterns as a matter of course, otherwise the shell will expand any wildcard characters in them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
find -iname '*.xml'
```

Otherwise, your shell expands `*.xml` to `XYZ.xml`, and the command that actually gets executed is

```
find -iname XYZ.xml
```

The reason it works if there are no XML files in the current directory is that shells generally leave wildcards unexpanded if they don't match anything.  In general, any time you want wildcards to be expanded by a program other than the shell (e.g. by `find`, `tar`, `scp`, etc.) you need to quote them so the shell won't try to expand them itself.

Comment: Thx, that's so simple, but I've been wondering how to get around that for months. I found that really weird, and to be a very inconsistent behavior, but now I understand since it's not find, but bash's fault.

Comment: It's not bash's "fault" per-se but yours for not quoting wildcards that you wanted to pass as arguments. This goes for all programs that accept shell input. The shell expands them as globs unless they are quoted or escaped.

Comment: I guess Olivier meant it in the meaning, that it is an issue of `bash`, not of `find`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to quote your argument like this:

```
find ./ -name '*.xml'
```

so that it gets passed to find instead of being expanded by the shell, then passed to find as the expanded version.

Comment: Ok, so if `*.xml` doesn't match anything in the current directory, it is passed on literally, which is why it works in the other case. Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards are expanded by the shell, not by the command. `find` is one of the few commands that performs wildcard matching that's similar to the shell, in its own time.

When you run `ls *.xml`, first the shell expands `*.xml` to the list of matching files, e.g. `file1.xml` `file2.xml` `file3.xml`, and then the shell calls `ls` with the resulting list of arguments `file1.xml` `file2.xml` `file3.xml`. That's why you see the same list of file names with `echo *.xml`, even though `echo` knows nothing about files and doesn't care whether its arguments are file names.

When you run `find . -name "*.xml"`:

1. The shell parses the command line to recognize special characters and split it into words and puntuation. Here there's just a list of words `find`, `.`, `-name`, `*.xml` where the `*` is quoted. Since `*` is quoted, it's an ordinary character as far as the shell is concerned.
2. The shell runs the command `find` with the specified list of arguments: `.`, `-name`, `*.xml`.
3. `find` looks for files whose name matches the pattern `*.xml` in any directory under the current directory.

When you run `find . -name *.xml` and there are no files matching `*.xml`:

1. The shell parses the command line to recognize special characters and split it into words and puntuation. Here there's just a list of words `find`, `.`, `-name`, `*.xml` where the `*` is not quoted.
2. Since the word `*.xml` contains an unquoted wildcard character, the shell performs filename generation. Since there are no matching file names, the pattern remains unexpanded.
3. The shell runs the command `find` with the resulting list of arguments, which is `.`, `-name`, `*.xml`.
4. `find` looks for files whose name matches the pattern `*.xml` in any directory under the current directory.

When you run `find . -name *.xml` and the current directory contains `file1.xml`, `file2.xml` and `file3.xml`:

1. The shell parses the command line to recognize special characters and split it into words and puntuation. Here there's just a list of words `find`, `.`, `-name`, `*.xml` where the `*` is not quoted.
2. Since the word `*.xml` contains an unquoted wildcard character, the shell performs filename generation: `*.xml` is replaced by the list of matching file names.
3. The shell runs the command `find` with the resulting list of arguments, which is `.`, `-name`, `file1.xml`, `file2.xml`, `file3.xml`.
4. `find` complains about a syntax error when it reaches `file2.xml`.

When you run `find . -name *.xml` and the current directory contains a single matching file `file.xml`:

1. The shell parses the command line to recognize special characters and split it into words and puntuation. Here there's just a list of words `find`, `.`, `-name`, `*.xml` where the `*` is not quoted.
2. Since the word `*.xml` contains an unquoted wildcard character, the shell performs filename generation: `*.xml` is replaced by the list of matching file names.
3. The shell runs the command `find` with the resulting list of arguments, which is `.`, `-name`, `file.xml`.
4. `find` sees a perfectly valid command, but it is probably not what you intended: `find` is told to look for files called `file.xml` in any directory, not to look for any file matching `*.xml`.

(Shell evaluation and expansion has a lot of other features. I only mentioned the ones that are relevant here.)

(What I describe is the default behavior of most common shells: sh, bash, dash, ksh, … Some shells can be configured to display an error instead of running a command with unexpanded wildcards, or to expand non-matching wildcards to an empty list. None of those would help here.)

Answer (score -1):

This works on Solaris 10:

`find /directory-to-search/* -prune -name "*gz"`

Comment: This would not search for names ending in `.xml`.

Answer (score -2):

Please try:

```
find ./ -name *.xml
```

Comment: I've just tried that, same result.

Comment: I've tried it, and it works. On GNU bash 4.2.8

Comment: This doesn't work when the glob matches anything in the current directory. It is the wrong syntax! The `*` should always be quoted or escaped to pass it to find.