# How to use find command with wildcard when current directory contains a match?

Tags: command-line, find, wildcards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [find not recursive when file at top](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13977/find-not-recursive-when-file-at-top)

I'm having some confusion with the find command.

If I type:

```
find . -name *.xml
```

or

```
find ./ -name *.xml
```

I receive a list of all the `xml` files in subdirectories of the current directory, UNLESS the current directory contains an `xml` file, in which case I get:

```
find: paths must precede expression: foo.xml
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

What is the correct way to search for files with wildcard when the current directory may contain a match?