# Find doesn't want to find *.sh in certain level

Tags: shell, find, wildcards

I have a problem with `find`. It doesn't find *.sh files if I am in certain directory level. It does, however, find *.sql files.

```
/path$ cd do_not_upload/updates/1.1.1/
/path/do_not_upload/updates/1.1.1$ find . -path *.sh
./run_pre_update/002.sh
./run_pre_update/001.sh
./run_post_update/001.sh
/path/do_not_upload/updates/1.1.1$ find . -path *.sh
./run_pre_update/002.sh
./run_pre_update/001.sh
./run_post_update/001.sh
/path/do_not_upload/updates/1.1.1$ cd ..
/path/do_not_upload/updates$ find . -path *.sh
./1.1.3/run_pre_update/002.sh
./1.1.3/run_pre_update/001.sh
./1.1.3/run_post_update/001.sh
./1.1.1/run_pre_update/002.sh
./1.1.1/run_pre_update/001.sh
./1.1.1/run_post_update/001.sh
/path/do_not_upload/updates$ cd ..
/path/do_not_upload$ find . -path *.sh
./updates/1.1.3/run_pre_update/002.sh
./updates/1.1.3/run_pre_update/001.sh
./updates/1.1.3/run_post_update/001.sh
./updates/1.1.1/run_pre_update/002.sh
./updates/1.1.1/run_pre_update/001.sh
./updates/1.1.1/run_post_update/001.sh
/path/do_not_upload$ cd ..
/path$ find . -path *.sh
/path$ find . -path *.sql
./do_not_upload/updates/1.1.3/sql_migrations/002.sql
./do_not_upload/updates/1.1.3/sql_migrations/001.sql
./do_not_upload/updates/1.1.1/sql_migrations/002.sql
./do_not_upload/updates/1.1.1/sql_migrations/001.sql

$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

/path$ stat do_not_upload/
  File: ‘do_not_upload/’
  Size: 60          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 14h/20d Inode: 159862      Links: 3
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  jorgee)   Gid: ( 1000/  jorgee)
Access: 2014-09-10 14:02:34.449376973 -0300
Modify: 2014-09-10 13:54:13.805363567 -0300
Change: 2014-09-10 13:54:13.805363567 -0300
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Is `do_not_upload` a symlink?  Also, don't forget to quote the `*.sh` so the shell doesn't expand it.

Comment: @Mikel, no, its not a symlink. It is outputof rsync

Comment: Mind adding the output of `stat do_not_upload` to confirm?

Comment: Thanks!  I see your point about `do_not_upload/.../sql_migrations` too.

Comment: Altho I don't think it's the problem, can you try putting quotes around `*.sh` and `*.sql`?  It's a good habit anyway.

Comment: To @Mikel's point, try `find . -follow -path '*.sh'`.

Comment: @Mikel You seem to be right, adding `"` to the `*.sh` does work.... However I don't understand why it doesn't work for *.sh and does work for *.sql (without the `"`)

Comment: @Mikel maybe the answer lays in that there ARE files ending in .sh in that directory, from which I am starting the find. However, there are not .sql files. My guess now is that bash is expanding that to all the files in the directory ending with .sh

Comment: @Jorge That seems likely - iirc, the bash options `nullglob` and `failglob` can be used to change bashs behaviour when globbing fails a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix-like systems, `*.sh` is a glob expression that is expanded by the shell and the results are passed as arguments to the program being invoked.  If and only if there are no matching files will the glob expression be passed as-is.  You should get in the habit of quoting wildcards if you want them to be passed to the program you're running.

As an example, if you were to run `find . -path *.sh` from `/path/do_not_upload/updates/1.1.1/run_pre_update/`, the actual command being executed would be `find . -path 001.sh 002.sh`, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Note that this differs from MS-DOS and related systems, where glob expansion is done (or not done) by the program being invoked.

To prevent shell expansions, enclose the argument in double or even single quotes - that will pass it to the invoked program verbatim and thus let `find` do its own expansions:

```
$ find . -path '*.sh'
```

Comment: Note that the behavior of a glob when it does not match anything is not guaranteed.  In `bash` it is even configurable (as @Wieland mentioned in the comments above).

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13977/2421), but the reason you get no output is a bit different.

With `-path`, the argument must match the entire path (including the command line argument).  When `foo.sh` exists in the current directory, you're executing

```
find . -path foo.sh
```

Because `foo.sh` does not match `./foo.sh`, you get no output.

The solution is the same as the linked question: quote your wildcards if you don't want the shell to expand them.