# Script to recursively replace invalid characters in filenames, not directories, with rename

Tags: bash, find, zsh, rename, wildcards

I'm looking to write a script that will find and replace any characters other than `[^A-Za-z0-9._-]` in a specific file type (in this case `.avi`) with an underscore `_`. I want this to exec recursively from the current path. I'm using Ubuntu.

I do not want or need to change any folder names as I have control over those at the time of creation. Here's what I have now after referencing the following link:

[SE reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141086/how-can-i-use-rename-to-recursively-rename-everyting-to-uppercase)

```
find . -depth -exec rename 's!([^/]*\Z)/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g' *.avi {} +
```

I'm clearly missing something. Please help. :)

Comment: I think you need \; at the end of the -exec in find.  Not sure what the '+' does.

Comment: Tip: First get the -exec to work with something simple like `-exec ls {} \;`  Also get the rename to  work separately outside of the find.

Comment: @Ellipticalview The `{} +` will be replace with a batch of pathnames, this is standard `find` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why your code doesn't work

The wildcard pattern `*.avi` is expanded by the shell that runs `find` before running `find`, so its effect depends on whether there are `*.avi` files in the current directory or not. See [find not recursive when file at top](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13977/find-not-recursive-when-file-at-top) for more explanations. To expand `*.avi` in subdirectories, you'd need to do three things differently: quote the pattern so that the original shell doesn't expand it; arrange to run an additional shell in each subdirectory to perform the wildcard expansion; and look for directories only with the `find` command rather than any file type.

In addition, your code ends up calling `rename` on every file at any level under the current directory, including on subdirectories themselves, via `{} +`. So `rename` operates on directories, not just regular files.

Furthermore there's a syntax error in your Perl code.

#### Working solution with zsh

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc

zmv -n '(**/)(*.avi)(#qD^/)' '$1${2//[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]/_}'
```

`^/` is to select any type of file other than *directory*. Replace with `.` for *regular* files only. `-n` is for *dry-run*. Remove when happy.

#### Working solution with `find` and `rename`

With the perl-based variants of `rename` and a `find` implementation that supports `-execdir`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -depth -name '*[!a-zA-Z0-9._-]*.avi' ! -type d -execdir \
  rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]/_/g' {} +
```

There are a few caveats with that approach though:

- That runs *at least* one `rename` instance per directory containing files to rename (one `rename` per file with some `find` implementations/versions where `-execdir ... {} +` is actually the same as `-execdir ... {} \;`. (`zmv` runs one `mv` per file, but you can make `mv` builtin with `zmodload zsh/files` to speed it up).
- With `-execdir`, `find` runs the command *in the directory* that contains those files and passes a path relative to that directory to the command. Some `find` implementations (the GNU one) add a `./` prefix to the files, some don't. Some variants of `rename` do accept options *after* the perl expression, which means that if you have a file whose name starts with `-`, it could cause problem.
- we have to use `LC_ALL=C` for `-name` to work even if file names contain sequences of bytes that otherwise wouldn't form valid characters in the locale. `rename` inherits that and anyway in most variants only works with ASCII. That means however that it will replace multi-byte characters with as many `_` as the character has bytes. For instance, it would rename a UTF-8 `stéphane` to `st__phane` instead of `st_phane`. `zsh` is OK because it will convert both multi-byte characters and all bytes that can't be decoded to characters into one `_` character each.
- contrary to `zsh`'s `zmv`, it won't perform sanity checks (like that 2 files are not going to end up having the same name like `a+b.avi` and `a@b.avi`) prior to start renaming. `rename` should however not overwrite existing files.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and examples. Now, specifically referring to zsh's zmv, what is the behavior when an open file is encountered?

Comment: @senor_nose, `zmv` eventually calls `mv`. Whether the file is open or not has no influence. Renaming files is just changing the contents of directory files.

Comment: Thank you again for following up.If a file was being written to, and the file name is changed, then there would be the possibility of  a write severance (i.e., application continues to write to a file that has the character I'd like to remove, it gets removed by mv, application has lost it's write destination). Is there a way to manage this?

Comment: @senor_nose, that kind of problem could only arise when `mv` moves the file to a different file system (where `mv` needs to do a copy+delete). If it only does a rename, the file renames the same file all along, only the directory entries that refer to the file are renamed, again, `mv` (the `rename()` system call) modifies the directory, not the file (it only changes the ctime (change status time) of the file).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that

```
rename 's/[^A-Za-z0-9.-]/_/g' -- *.avi
```

would properly rename all the files with a `.avi` filename suffix in the current directory, you would be able to apply this to all directories beneath the current one (including the current one) with

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        ( cd "$dirpath" && rename "s/[^A-Za-z0-9.-]/_/g" -- *.avi )
    done' sh {} +
```

For batches of found directories, this would execute a short in-line script that changes into the found directory and executes the `rename` command.

Comment: @PauloTomé That `sh` will be placed in `$0` and used in any error messages that the shell produces. It is not part of the positional parameters.