# ERROR. Rename files AND DIRECTORIES with windows reserved characters

Tags: rename

I had a hard drive that couldn't mount on Linux Mint and to fix it I had to go to Windows and do `chkdsk /f e:`. chkdsk fixed the problem but it renamed every file with special characters and moved those files to a `found.000` directory. So now I have to move and rename again those files as they were before. If I run a command from time to time to rename the files with special characters I could avoid that happening again.

I want to recursively **rename files AND DIRECTORIES** from the current directory. The **newlines** should be replaced **for space**, the **characters** `< > : " \ | ? *` should be **removed** or better yet substituted for similar characters which aren't reserved and the **spaces** at the **start and end** of a filename should be **removed**. Here is an example of **what I want**:

```
rename(' Fîlenämè\n\r\n$@<>:"\|?* \n ', 'Fîlenämè $@')
```

Here is what would be **even better**:

```
rename(' Fîlenämè\n\r\n$@<>:"\|?* \n ', 'Filename $@')
```

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563424/96101) it should be something like this:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -depth -execdir rename -n 's/[\r\n]+/ /g; s/:/./g; s/[\|]/-/g; s/[<>"?*]//g; s/[ \f\t\v]+$//g; s/^[ \f\t\v]+//g' {} +
```

I need to ignore the `..Trash-1000` directory as this command is giving me **input/output ERRORS** and the command stops working. Having a script that handles those errors in case there are files in that directory that can be renamed would be perfect.

I was told to prune the `..Trash-1000` directory as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/376078/96101). I also took a look at [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209080/96101). But doing this is not working:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -depth -path ./..Trash-1000 -prune -o -print -execdir rename -n 's/[\r\n]+/ /g; s/:/./g; s/[\|]/-/g; s/[<>"?*]//g; s/[ \f\t\v]+$//g; s/^[ \f\t\v]+//g' {} +
```

And it's still not deleting spaces at the start and end of the filenames.

I had to rewrite my question as the question [Script to recursively replace invalid characters in filenames, not directories, with rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563131/script-to-recursively-replace-invalid-characters-in-filenames-not-directories) didn't answer mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename files and directories with windows or linux reserved characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572389/rename-files-and-directories-with-windows-or-linux-reserved-characters)

Comment: Again? I had to rewrite the question to emphasize the difference and I specifically said it isn't working.

Comment: Are you asking how to prune the `..Trash-1000` path in your `find` command? If so, take a look at [Explain find's -path and -prune options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/376075/explain-finds-path-and-prune-options)

Comment: I still don't see the difference between this question, your previous one, and the marked duplicate. Perhaps examples of what you're trying to match would help.

Comment: I added an example of what I'm trying to do. The prune is not working for me. Is it because I'm using a relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pruning the directory giving input/output errors the command can be executed once for each of the other directories.

This is the command that I used to remove windows reserved characters:

```
find . -execdir rename -n 's/[\r\n]+/ /g;
                           s/:/./g;
                           s/[\|]/-/g;
                           s/[<>"?*]//g;
                           s/[ \f\t\v]+$//g;
                           s/^[ \f\t\v]+//g' {} \;
```

It turns newlines to spaces, then substitutes `:` for `.`, then changes `\|` with `-`, then removes `<>"?*`, then deletes spaces at the end of the filename and then it does the same for spaces at the start.